# Call Custom phtml file in static block

Tags: magento-1.9, static-block, phtml

In my theme package i create a `custom.phtml` file in `theme_name/default/template/custom/custom.phtml` , i want to call this file in static block i try this method :

`{{block type="core/template" template="theme_name/default/template/custom/custom.phtml"}}`

but nothing appears.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to include the theme's directory in the template path, Magento will automatically use the current theme and fallback structure. For example:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="page/html/home.phtml"}}
```

Or in your case:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="custom/custom.phtml"}}
```